# slideToggle problems in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using slideToggle to open a table inside a web page div, which works kind of like accordian. The code works fine in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox, it opens the table section then "whites it out" immediately. The allotted space is still there, and when I toggle the button to close the section, the underlying table and its contents briefly appear and then vanishes as the "whited out" section closes back up. Very weird. Any ideas?

```
$("#button").click(function toggleform (e) {
e.preventDefault();
  $("#div1").slideToggle('2000',"swing", function () {
    // Animation complete.
});      
});
```

Firefox is v.23.0.1

Comment: this JS code has not much to do with your issue. Take again a look at your CSS, positions, parents positions, display properties, even paddings and other stuff.

Comment: A jsfiddle will be good enough to help you.

Comment: Use plugin there are lots of it.

Comment: @KashifRaza which plugin do you mean?

Comment: I have found thru testing that if I remove the  <td> tags from the table, the problem goes away in Firefox. But of course, the table is rendered useless. I need to use <td> tags.

Comment: validate your html, might be invalid

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The JS was good. In the overall HTML structure of the page, I was trying to open the slideToggling table *inside* an existing and larger table's TR. While this caused no problems for Chrome and IE, it apparently caused FF to "inherit" table properties from elsewhere on the page.

This caused the sliding section to "blank out" when opening. So I created a new TR in the "parent" table to contain the slider section, and now it works properly in all three browsers.